# How to keep divs fixed while scrolling mouse with table?

Tags: html, css

Below I am trying to make the first 3 red divs fixed. I just wanted to scroll the table rows that are under these divs and have a scroll

Notice that when I scroll the divs that are in red, they go down too, but I didn't want that to happen.

I created symbolic values ​​just to illustrate this problem. Can anyone help to solve this problem?

I couldn't find a solution to this problem, even going into other forums and applying the same solution logic I still couldn't solve it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }

    .navbar {
      overflow: auto;
      background-color: blue;
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      height: 700px;

      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 460px);
      grid-auto-rows: 300px ;
      grid-auto-flow: dense;
      grid-gap: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      resize: horizontal;
    }

    .navbar div{
      border-radius: 10px;
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="navbar">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <table>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3</th>
      <th>col4</th>
      <th>col5</th>
      <th>col6</th>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>      
    </table>
    <table>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3</th>
      <th>col4</th>
      <th>col5</th>
      <th>col6</th>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>      
    </table>
    <table>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3</th>
      <th>col4</th>
      <th>col5</th>
      <th>col6</th>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>      
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    html {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
    }
    .fixed-box {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 460px);
      grid-auto-rows: 100px;
      grid-gap: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .fixed-box div{
      border-radius: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: red;
    }

    .navbar {
      overflow: auto;
      background-color: blue;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 460px);
      grid-auto-rows: 300px ;
      grid-auto-flow: dense;
      grid-gap: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      resize: horizontal;
      
      position: relative;
      top: calc(100px + 20px);
      width: 100%;
      height: 700px;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <section class="fixed-box">  
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </section>
  <div class="navbar">
    <table>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3</th>
      <th>col4</th>
      <th>col5</th>
      <th>col6</th>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>      
    </table>
    <table>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3</th>
      <th>col4</th>
      <th>col5</th>
      <th>col6</th>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>      
    </table>
    <table>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3</th>
      <th>col4</th>
      <th>col5</th>
      <th>col6</th>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>      
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      overflow: auto;
      position: relative;
    }

    .navbar {
      overflow: auto;
      background-color: blue;
      position: sticky;
      width: 100%;
      height: 700px;
      top:0;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 460px);
      grid-auto-rows: 300px ;
      grid-auto-flow: dense;
      grid-gap: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      resize: horizontal;
    }

    .navbar div{
      border-radius: 10px;
    
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="navbar">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <table>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3</th>
      <th>col4</th>
      <th>col5</th>
      <th>col6</th>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>      
    </table>
    <table>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3</th>
      <th>col4</th>
      <th>col5</th>
      <th>col6</th>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>      
    </table>
    <table>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3</th>
      <th>col4</th>
      <th>col5</th>
      <th>col6</th>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>      
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The new code would be:

```
.navbar div {
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
}
```

And in action:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 460px);
  grid-auto-rows: 300px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  resize: horizontal;
}

.navbar div {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  /*new code from here*/
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="navbar">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <table>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3</th>
      <th>col4</th>
      <th>col5</th>
      <th>col6</th>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3</th>
      <th>col4</th>
      <th>col5</th>
      <th>col6</th>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3</th>
      <th>col4</th>
      <th>col5</th>
      <th>col6</th>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
        <td>val3</td>
        <td>val4</td>
        <td>val5</td>
        <td>val6</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple you can Change `position:absolute` to `position:fixed;`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).